# Iterating through an array of objects and getting the next name property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

how would I go about iterating over this array:

```
const data = [
    {
        name: "Punnerrukset",
        sarjat: "3",
        videoId: "-Mbr55h3BeQ",
    },
    {
        name: "Penkkipunnerrus",
        sarjat: "3",
        videoId: "-6oBbHy_zjM",
    },
    {
        name: "Pystypunnerrus",
        sarjat: "3",
        videoId: "2yjwXTZQDDI",
    },
];
```

I have implemented a FlatList to render the data and on each react-native-snap-carousel slide it shows the "name" property from the data. What if I wanted to show the next name property in the array of objects. So, for example, current slide says "Punnerrukset" and then there would be a paragraph "Next up: Penkkipunnerrus", then on the next slide (Penkkipunnerrus) it would say "Next up: "Pystypunnerrus" and so on... Hope you get the point. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do for this is, let's say your `currentIndex` is 0.
Then your
`data[currentIndex+1].name`
will have the value you need to show. When you are at the last index i.e. `currentIndex === data.length - 1` then your next value will be at index 0;

So your nextValue becomes:

```
 nextValue = data[( currentIndex + 1 ) % data.length].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for…in` loop. `for…of` is helpful when you just want to use the single element in the array but this will allow you to get an element relative to the current one (in this case, index+1);

```js
for(const i in data) {
let vid = data[i];
let nextVid = data[parseInt(i)+1];
}
```

On the first iteration, `vid` is

```js
{
        name: "Punnerrukset",
        sarjat: "3",
        videoId: "-Mbr55h3BeQ",
    }
```

And `nextVid` is

```js
{
        name: "Penkkipunnerrus",
        sarjat: "3",
        videoId: "-6oBbHy_zjM",
    }
```